# Cada Linha do banco de dados entrar em uma DIV separada

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, mysqli

Boa tarde 
Estou tentando fazer uma consulta MySQLi , ou seja , quero que cada linha do banco de dados entra em uma div separada , Pesquisei e nao achei nada semelhando o que acho fica de uma forma dificil de entender

Codigo HTML

```html
<div id="inicio" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details">
  <div class="well profile_view">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h4 class="brief"><i>Digital Strategist</i></h4>
      <div class="left col-xs-7">
        <h2 id="inicio"></h2>
        <p><strong>About: </strong> Web Designer / UX / Graphic Artist / Coffee Lover </p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><i class="fa fa-building"></i> Address: </li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Phone #: </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right col-xs-5 text-center">
        <img src="../images/img.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 bottom text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
        <p id="inicio" class="ratings">
          <a>4.0</a>
          <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span></a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-user">
                                                    </i> <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-user"> </i> View Profile
                                                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("document").ready(function() {

  //CarregarFuncionarios
  $.getJSON("../include/carrFunc.php", function(data) {
    var items = [];
    i = 0;
    $.each(data, function(i) {
      items.push("<option value='" + data[i].idFuncionario + "'>" +
        data[i].nomeFunc + "</option>");
    });
    $("#inicio").append(items);
  });

});
```

PHP

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

$sql = "SELECT idFuncionario,nomeFunc FROM tbfuncionario;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $data = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
    //print_r ($data);
} else {
    echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado.";
}       
$conn->close();
//echo "<br>";
echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```

[image: Imagem Exemplo]

Comment: O que dá `console.log(data);` na callback do getJSON? Esse HTML que tens na página é o que cada linha da base de dados deve preencher?

Comment: Não entendi bem o uso do <option> ali no javascript

Comment: @Sergio alias coloquei coisas a mais ali , eu tenho esse formulario pronto em HTML porem queria usar os efeitos que ele possui

Comment: @GeekSilva entao eu usei o mesmo codigo que uso para carregar as combobox .. nao tenho muito conhecimento em web .. mas queria que cada linha do banco preencher uma div na pagina

Comment: Cara, voce tem mais de um "id" com o mesmo nome "inicio" alocado em varias Tags, assim o browser nunca vai colocar no lugar certo :(
Outro ponto é que voce esta dando um append de um <option> sem ter nenhum <select> na sua pagina :(

Comment: Explicando melhor ...preciso que aparece os campos de cada usuario ex:nome , endereço e etc, ... e preciso que aparece em divs separadas , de acordo com cada dados

Comment: O que dá `console.log(data);` na callback do getJSON?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
(anonymous) @ VM5597:1

Comment: @Sergio varios object   ) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]   dessa forma fica na callback

Comment: @Somdesp ok, e o que dá `console.log(typeof data, JSON.stringify(data));`?

Comment: @Sergio Aparece todos os dados do banco

Comment: @Somdesp podes colocar aqui um exemplo de um desses objetos? para podermos responder melhor?

Comment: @Sergio uma das linhas {"idFuncionario":"7","nomeFunc":"Anderson Silva"} isso que preciso que aparece em cada div ou separadas no html

Comment: E no HTML onde devem ser inseridos esses dados?

Comment: @Sergio no HTML quando uso o $("#inicio").append(items[i]); no JS e    <div name="inicio" id="inicio"> no html aparece tudo dentro da mesma div

Comment: Mas em que elemento do HTML? em que div ou span? para poder dar um exemplo de como montares isso. E já agora, esses objetos só têm 2 chaves (idFuncionario e nomeFunc)?

Comment: @Sergio eu queria colocar em div .. de inicio iria ter essas chaves depois eu iria adicionar mais ...vou colocar uma imagem no final para entender melhor

Comment: @Sergio adicionei a imagem do exemplo que quero fazer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazeres isso tens de iterar o JSON que recebes mais ou menos como tens na pergunta.

Podes fazer isso numa concatenação gigante de HTML, ou usar templates ou pedaços de HTML já existente.

Usando o teu HTML, e o JSON que mostraste podias fazer algo como no exemplo em baixo. É ao estilo de template, e é uma boa maneira para aprender e ter controlo sobre o código. A ideia é colocar `+ obj.chave +` onde for preciso.:

```js
function gerarFunctionario(obj){
 return '<div class="well profile_view">'+
    '<div class="col-sm-12">'+
      '<h4 class="brief"><i>Digital Strategist</i></h4>'+
      '<div class="left col-xs-7">'+
        '<h2>'+obj.nomeFunc+'</h2>'+
        '<p><strong>About: </strong> Web Designer / UX / Graphic Artist / Coffee Lover </p>'+
        '<ul class="list-unstyled">'+
          '<li><i class="fa fa-building"></i> Address: </li>'+
          '<li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Phone #: </li>'+
        '</ul>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="right col-xs-5 text-center">'+
        '<img src="../images/img.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive">'+
      '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-xs-12 bottom text-center">'+
      '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">'+
        '<p id="inicio" class="ratings">'+
          '<a>4.0</a>'+
          '<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>'+
          '<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>'+
          '<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>'+
          '<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>'+
          '<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span></a>'+
        '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">'+
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-user">'+
            '</i> <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> </button>'+
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">'+
             '<i class="fa fa-user"> </i> View Profile'+
         '</button>'+
      '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>';
}

var data = [{
    "idFuncionario": "7",
    "nomeFunc": "Anderson Silva"
  },
  {
    "idFuncionario": "2",
    "nomeFunc": "Maria Silva"
  }
]

var html = data.map(gerarFunctionario).join('');
$("#inicio").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inicio" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details">

</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou.. Muito Obrigado

Comment: obs: Para puxar do banco so adiciono as string dentro do vetor ne

Comment: @Somdesp coloca as duas ultimas linhas dentro da função do ajax, onde tens o `$.each` e apaga o que tens lá agora. A função `gerarFunctionario` podes colocar na 2a linha do código que está na pergunta. Antes do `getJSON`.

Comment: Consegui agora estou com outro problema kkk e para fazer o updade por exemplo : estou usando a funcao parecida para insert porem nao consigo usar o ID dos botoes dentro do Json

Comment: @Somdesp faz outra pergunta. Lembra-te que só podes ter 1 ID com o mesmo nome na página, ou seja não podes repetir IDs.

Comment: Obrigado acabei de fazer a pergunta